# Can't get markers to work on google maps

Tags: google-maps, marker

I've been trying for ages to get a marker on this map, same location as center, but can't get it to work.

```
<html>

  <head>
<style>
  #map {
    width: 100%x;
    height: 400px;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.909968, 10.748012),
      zoom: 16,
      zoomControl: true,
      scaleControl: true,
      scrollwheel: false,
      disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
```

I've tried following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple), but I can't get it to work..

Any ideas? I had it working on my site using an iframe, but had issues scrolling past the full width map without getting caught zooming in, so I'm looking for a way to make this code to replace it.

Comment: There is no marker in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Following the example you [link to](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) works for me (setting the marker to the map center):

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.909968, 10.748012),
    zoom: 16,
    zoomControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

  // from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    // change the position to the map center
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```